# How to find maximum in SparseDoubleMatrix2D (Java Colt library)? or even in a 1D Matrix for that matter

Tags: java, matrix, max, sparse-matrix, colt

On the overview website http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/api/index.html it is said that via Columnwise Data Analysis the maximum value(of a column) can be found.
However I searched for quite a long while and cannot find the method!

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you want, but might help others looking for similar things:

In parallel colt, there are direct methods for finding the max and min values, together with location: methods `getMaxLocation()` and `getMinLocation()` are present in both the classes `cern.colt.matrix.tdouble.DoubleMatrix1D` and `cern.colt.matrix.tdouble.DoubleMatrix2D`

Answer (score 0):

It's cern.jet.stat.Descriptive.max(DoubleArrayList).
You'll have to build such a list with `new DoubleArrayList(doubleMatrix2D.viewColumn(iColumn).toArray())`.

Comment: Thanks that works! Is there another method that will give me the array-position at which this maximum value is located?

Comment: I don't think so; you'll have to write that yourself.  You should probably write a method that returns an object containing the maximum and the index, or just the index if that is only what you need.  You could start from the code in Descriptive.max.